# Telnet alternative that supports cursor

Tags: remote-access, telnet

I'm looking for a simple Telnet-like application that would allow me to connect to a server running on my local machine.

That server implements a REPL shell to my backend application. Telnet doesn't work well for me because it doesn't support the terminal features like navigation with a cursor. Navigation with a cursor is ALL I want. The app will be used strictly from a local machine via the loopback interface telnet localhost 6789.

I came across such application a few years ago, but I just can't find it now.

Just to clarify

> Yes I do realize that Telnet is insecure. I'll make it secure with an ssh tunnel on a remote machine if I need to. But I need a client that would allow to open an interactive session to type commands in. Typing commands is an awful experience when you can't use a cursor

Comment: Which o/s should the client run on? And should it be gratis, or do you have a budget?

Comment: And speaking of an SSH tunnel: why not simply using a terminal? What is listening "on the other end", waiting for you to "type commands"? That might be relevant to the program you're looking for ;)

Comment: You said "Telnet doesn't work well for me because it doesn't support the terminal features like navigation with a cursor." I don't think this is true. In 1996 I used telnet and vi on solaris, hp/ux, ... Sometimes you had to set the matching TERM environment variable to get it working.

Comment: @guetti Okay. I'll investigate what's the value of the TERM variable.

Comment: What do you mean by "supports cursor"? Are you saying that you want a Telnet client with a GUI?

Answer (score 0):

Georgia Softworks universal terminal server can provide mouse support for PuTTY and Android Telnet clients and other clients that are capable of sending xterm style mouse report type 1002. It allows you to use mouse clicks within your console application. https://www.georgiasoftworks.com/connectbot-client-android .